# On Flutter web with VoiceOver focus issue with TextFormFields

Tags: flutter, web, semantics, voiceover, textformfield

On flutter web, with VoiceOver on TextFormFields do not consistently get focus.
Please refer to the image. Observe that the accessibility focus has moved to second input while the input cursor is still on the first.

Please refer to the code at https://github.com/mfdcoder/flutter-form-voiceover

Steps to reproduce

1. Switch on Voiceover Using Ctl + Option + Right arrow navigate to the
2. TextFormField Continue navigating to 2nd, 3rd and 4th TextFormField
3. Observe that voice over announces that "You are in a text field. To enter text in this field type".
4. The input that has focus often does not accept what the user is typing.
5. The result is not consistent. The TextFormFields randomly get/don't get focus

The same can be reproduced on the flutter gallery demo app
https://gallery.flutter.dev/#/demo/text-field

Doctor summary (to see all details, run flutter doctor -v):
Flutter (Channel stable, 3.7.0, on macOS 12.5 21G72 darwin-x64, locale en-IN)
Android toolchain - develop for Android devices (Android SDK version 33.0.0)
Xcode - develop for iOS and macOS (Xcode 14.1)
Chrome - develop for the web
Android Studio (version 2021.2)
VS Code (version 1.75.1)
Connected device (5 available)
HTTP Host Availability

[Accessibility focus and form focus do not match](https://i.stack.imgur.com/LYnjh.png)

```
Semantics(
    focusable: true,
    focused: _addressLine2.hasFocus,
    child: TextFormField(
        autovalidateMode: AutovalidateMode.onUserInteraction,
        controller: _addressLine2Controller,
        keyboardType: TextInputType.text,
        textInputAction: TextInputAction.next,
        validator: (value) {
            if (value == null || value.isEmpty) {
                return 'Please enter some text in line 2';
            }
            return null;
        },
        inputFormatters: [LengthLimitingTextInputFormatter(255)],
        decoration: const InputDecoration(
        hintText: 'Address Line 2',
        labelText: 'Address Line 2',
        errorBorder: OutlineInputBorder(
          borderRadius: BorderRadius.all(Radius.circular(6)),
          borderSide: BorderSide(color: Colors.red),
        )),
        focusNode: _addressLine2,
        onSaved: (value) {
            _city.requestFocus();
        },
    ),
),
```

Answer (score 0):

Wrap your home screen with [FocusTrabesalGroup](https://api.flutter.dev/flutter/widgets/WidgetOrderTraversalPolicy-class.html) it changes focus order in widget hierarchy order for flutter web apps.

```
return MaterialApp(
  home:FocusTraversalGroup(
    policy: WidgetOrderTraversalPolicy(),
    child: Scaffold(
      body: Container(),
    ),
  ),
);
```